# Extjs 6 ViewModel does not work fine

Tags: viewmodel, extjs6

I'm developing an application using Extjs6. I have a sign page. I have two textfields as follows:

```
items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'email',
    emptyText: 'Email',
    bind : '{inEmail}',
    labelWidth: 60,
    anchor: '100%',
    hideLabel: true,
    allowBlank : false,
    margin: '15 5 0 5',
    listeners: listeners
}, {
    xtype: 'textfield',
    reference: 'password',
    name: 'password',
    bind : '{inpassword}',
    emptyText: 'Password',
    inputType: 'password',
    labelSeparator: '',
    labelWidth: 60,
    anchor: '100%',
    hideLabel: true,
    allowBlank : false,
    margin: '15 5 0 5',
    listeners: listeners
}]
```

I have a button like this:

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: '<span style="color: white ">Enter</span>',
    anchor: '100%',
    handler: 'signin',
    bind: {
        disabled: '{!signinBtn}'
    },
    margin: '-5 5 25 5'
}
```

In viewModel I define a formula:

```
formulas: 
{
    signinBtn: function (get) {
        var fn = get('inEmail'), ln = get('inpassword');
        return (fn && ln);
    }
}
```

But when I browse to this page, sometimes it does not work. But when I change `disabled` to `hidden`, it works fine.

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: don't add `allowBlank: false` to the `textfield`.

I've created a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/14cv) to answer your question. I've added a `console.log(fn && ln);` to see on the console when the formula is evaluated.

The fiddle works as you expected **if** you don't add the `allowBlank: false` to your `textfield`. If you add that property, the formula is not evaluated when you clear the `textfield` contents.